# what is the coding logic behind a gauge/ speedometer

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am new to JavaFx/ GUI animation. I am trying to implement an analog meter in JavaFx. So far I have designed the FXML view which looks as shown below.

[image: Analog meter]

Now I wanted the pointer to rotate with respect to the input value (say to 0.5 in my case). Since it is a design/ vector drawing, I believe it is only possible to rotate the pointer to respective degrees (say 30 deg that corresponds to 0.5). Is this the logic behind all the GUI meters or anything else exists? If this is the logic, then would anyone let me know the formula/ equation that does this? I mean converting decimal numerical values to degrees? Would JavaFx take into account minutes/ seconds in the rotate function as well?

Comment: "Is this the logic behind all the GUI meters". What meters are you referring to?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement a linear function such that f(-1.0)==-60.0, and f(1.0)==60.0?

Comment: @jameslarge: Yes. If you have any other better idea pls let me know

Comment: sounds like f(x) = x*60.0.  Right?

Comment: @jameslarge the gauge doesn't actually look linear, though...

Comment: Why don't you check this out..
http://harmoniccode.blogspot.com/2012/06/jfxtras-series-radial-gauge.html

He's awesome at controls..
He has a bitbucket repo with all the sources as well... you could see how he does it.

Comment: Or this one http://slothsoft.de/en/content/creating-custom-control-javafx-gauge-bar

Comment: @Inge : yes I visited the link before but did not find the apt logic I am looking for.

Comment: @jdub1581: I am having a look at it. It looks cool though. Just yet to figure out.

Comment: @jameslarge: Even I had the same equation in mind, but not sure whether it is right way of doing!

Comment: @James_D it's not one gauge:  It's two:  The one on the left looks like the Vertical Speed Indicator from a General Aviation aircraft.  It goes from -1500 feet per minute (descending) to +1500 FPM (climbing).  That's totally linear.  I don't recognize what's on the right hand side.  I don't know what goes from 2 to 6 and back to 2.